# Law of total expectations. E[E[Y|X]] = E[Y]

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, conditional-expectation

I was trying to understand the proof of the law of total expectations, but I have two questions that I can't answer. What happen from line 3 to line 4? and how we conclude that integral of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)$

[image]

I have the intuition that $f_{x|y}(x|y)$ (or the conditional PDF) is equal to $f_{x,y}(x,y)$ because we are defining $Y=y$ and $X=x$ for each conditional expectation ($f_{x|y}(X=x|Y=y)$) which is equal to summation of those r.v. but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, in the discrete case, one has that
\begin{align*}
p_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{p_{X,Y}(x,y)}{p_{Y}(y)}
\end{align*}

On the other hand, in the absolutely continuous case, one has that
\begin{align*}
f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}
\end{align*}

The second expression justifies the transition from line 3 to line 4.

You can also think about the conditional expectations as follows.

Given the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\textbf{P})$ and the random variable $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\textbf{P})\to(\textbf{R},\mathcal{B}(\textbf{R}))$, let us consider a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$.

We define the conditional expectation $\textbf{E}(X|\mathcal{G})$ as the almost surely unique random variable s.t.

- $\textbf{E}(X|\mathcal{G})$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable,
- For every $B\in\mathcal{G}$, it holds that

$$\int_{B}X\mathrm{d}\textbf{P} = \int_{B}\textbf{E}(X|\mathcal{G})\mathrm{d}\textbf{P}$$

If we interpret $\sigma$-algebras as the information we have about the events whose occurrence we can judge, this means that $\textbf{E}(X|\mathcal{G})$ is the best approximation of $X$ based on the (restricted) information $\mathcal{G}$.

This should be sufficient to conclude the proposed claim, since
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}(X|Y) = \textbf{E}(X|\sigma(Y))
\end{align*}

where $\sigma(Y)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$.

Hopefully this helps!